# Django Cannot Add Model to Admin Site

Tags: django

I can't add new model to django's admin site. There is only one app can display its models and the other apps cannot add their models to admin site.

Here is my settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
'django.contrib.admin',
# Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
# 'django.contrib.admindocs',
'Home',
'Scope',
'Trend',
'Log',
'Lab',
'Club',
'Article',
'Search',
'page_test',
```

Here is the urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from cretus import views
# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
# Examples:
# url(r'^$', 'cretus.views.home', name='home'),
# url(r'^cretus/', include('cretus.foo.urls')),

# Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
# url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
#url(r'^$', include('Home.urls')),
url(r'^$', include('page_test.urls')),
url(r'^page/', include('Home.urls')),
url(r'^search/', include('Search.urls')),
url(r'^test/', include('page_test.urls')),
#url(r'artistsearch/', include('Search.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^artscopes/', include('Scope.urls')),
url(r'^trend/', include('Trend.urls')),
url(r'^log/', include('Log.urls')),
url(r'^lab/', include('Lab.urls')),
url(r'^club/', include('Club.urls')),
url(r'^privacy/$', views.privacy, name='privacy'),
url(r'thanks/$', views.thanks, name='thanks'),
url(r'^contest/$', views.contestForm, name='contest'),
url(r'^terms/$', views.terms, name='terms'),
#url(r'^test/$', views.test, name='test'),
#url(r'^(?P<title>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{0,100})/$', views.getArticleByTitle, name='test'),
#url(r'^article/', include('Article.urls')),
url(r'^article/', include('page_test.urls')),
# Apps
url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor.urls')),
url(r'^sitemap.xml$', views.sitemap, name='sitemap'),
url(r'^googlesearch/$', views.googlesearch, name='googlesearch'),
url(r'^legal/$', views.legal, name='legal'),
url(r'^', views.error, name='error'),
)
```

Here is one of the admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from Lab.models import AttendeeInfo

class AttendeeInfoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('fname', 'lname', 'email', 'video_url', 'package_name')
admin.site.register(AttendeeInfo, AttendeeInfoAdmin)
```

Comment: What's happening? What error message do you get?

Comment: @janos Actually the user I used in the admin console did not have the permission to check this model. After granting the permission, I can see it in the admin console now.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved. It is because the permission has not been granted to this user. So next time when you found you have done all of the procedures but still cannot find your model in the admin console, you may need to check this user's permission.